# sharepoint custom style for page in edit mode

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, master-pages

I want the following code snippet in master page to run if the current loaded page is in edit mode as follows:

```
<!-- If edit mode, then add the following script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.documentElement.className += ' edit-mode';
</script>
<!-- End if -->
```

simply, my script will add an `edit-mode` class to the `html` tag, that's it.

how can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel control.  This control will process the information included in this tag when the page is in the Edit mode.

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" id="IncludeEditModeClass" > 
    <asp:Content>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                document.documentElement.className += ' edit-mode';
        </script>
    </asp:Content> 
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

Comment: great solution!, the only drawback is that I have to include this tag in every page layout, cause I couldn't inject it into the masterpage, but beside that I love it, thank you @rossri so much ^_^

Answer (score 0):

since there are no SharePoint experts, I have done a workaround to solve my problem, and below my solution in two versions, first in jQuery, and second using pure JavaScript,

mainly i tried to look for a special classes that exists only in edit mode, for example `.ms-SPZoneLabel` is the class that wraps a web part zone in edit mode, `.edit-mode-panel` is a class that wraps a field to entering data in article pages, and `.ewiki-margin` in wiki pages...

```
// jQuery version
$(function(){
    if ($('.ms-SPZoneLabel, .edit-mode-panel, .ewiki-margin').length) {
        document.documentElement.className += ' edit-mode';
    }
});

// pure javascript way
(function(){

    // defining fall back getElementsByClassName if not exist (IE) 
    if(!document.getElementsByClassName) {
        document.getElementsByClassName = function(cl) {
            var retnode = [];
            var myclass = new RegExp('\\b'+cl+'\\b');
            var elem = this.getElementsByTagName('*');
            for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
                var classes = elem[i].className;
                if (myclass.test(classes)) {
                    retnode.push(elem[i]);
                } 
            }
            return retnode;
        };
    }
    // then checking if there's any webpart zone in the page
    if( document.getElementsByClassName('ms-SPZoneLabel').length || 
        document.getElementsByClassName('edit-mode-panel').length || 
        document.getElementsByClassName('ewiki-margin').length) {
        document.documentElement.className += ' edit-mode';
    }

})();
```

if someone have a better solution (like an ASP tag to determine that on server side)
please write down your solution

Comment: I am starting a bounty, can anyone provide a better clean solution ??

Answer (score 0):

This code does work if you use it as a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:if%20(document.forms['aspnetForm']['MSOLayout_InDesignMode']%20!=%20null)%20document.forms['aspnetForm']['MSOLayout_InDesignMode'].value%20=%201;if%20(document.forms['aspnetForm']['MSOAuthoringConsole_FormContext']%20!=%20null)%20document.forms['aspnetForm']['MSOAuthoringConsole_FormContext'].value%20=%201;theForm.submit();
```

I tried to convert it to plain Javascript, but it won't work in my firefox Javascript Console.

```
SP_EditPage: function(){
    var thisdocument = window.content.document;
    if (thisdocument.forms['aspnetForm']['MSOLayout_InDesignMode'] != null) 
        thisdocument.forms['aspnetForm']['MSOLayout_InDesignMode'].value = 1;
    if (thisdocument.forms['aspnetForm']['MSOAuthoringConsole_FormContext'] != null) 
        thisdocument.forms['aspnetForm']['MSOAuthoringConsole_FormContext'].value = 1;
        theForm.submit();   
},
```

I am quite interested if anyone can get it to work in plain javascript!  It tells me:
  Error: TypeError: thisdocument.forms.aspnetForm is undefined
  Source File: Javascript Command
  Line: 2

The bookmarklet came from this fellow's site:
  http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-developer-bookmarklets/

Here is another one.  It starts the edit page with the sidebar open.  This one works fine for me:

```
SP_EditPage: function(){
    var thisdocument = getBrowser().contentWindow.document;
    if(thisdocument.location.href.search('ToolPaneView=') == -1 ){
        if (thisdocument.location.search.indexOf('?') == 0){
            thisdocument.location=(thisdocument.location.href + '&ToolPaneView=2'); 
        }else{
            thisdocument.location=(thisdocument.location.href + '?ToolPaneView=2'); 
        } 
    } else {
        thisdocument.location=thisdocument.location.href;
    }   
},
```

Comment: @anasnakawa Well, if you only needed it to aid admins, the bookmarklet acts like a browser toolbar button that will let them automatically enter edit mode.  I have adapted the code to make it work inside a firefox toolbar button, which is why I have var thisdocument = getBrowser().congentWindow.document  - if you just want the code to run in the regular html page, you would change that part to just window.document.  Now, you can put that javascript in your master page, if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: ok, but i don't want a button that let me enter edit-mode, i just want to add a css class called 'edit-mode' to the html tag, so i can fix and align some styles when the page is viewed in edit mode!!
looks like you got the whole idea wrong my friend

Comment: Oh, I understand now... sorry!  I guess I misunderstood... And here I thought I was proposing something good!

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result you need to add the following piece of code in the masterpage.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var inDesignMode = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode.value;
  
  if (inDesignMode == "1")
  {
      // page is in edit mode
    <!-- If edit mode, then add the following script -->
    
     document.documentElement.className += ' edit-mode';
    
    <!-- End if -->
  
  }
  else
  {
      // page is in browse mode 
  } 

   </script>
```